# Save pictures while I scrape them from website using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I find a code on YouTube when I use it on my visual basic and debug it and find pictures but when i want to save them software gives me this message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJhK7.jpg).

```
Private Sub btnSaveImages_Click(ByVal sender As  _
    System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
    btnSaveImages.Click
    Dim dir_name As String = txtDirectory.Text
    If Not dir_name.EndsWith("\") Then dir_name &= "\"

    For Each pic As PictureBox In flpPictures.Controls
        Dim bm As Bitmap = pic.Image
        Dim filename As String = pic.Tag
        filename = _
            filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("/") + _
            1)
        Dim ext As String = _
            filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("."))
        Dim full_name As String = dir_name & filename

        Select Case ext
            Case ".bmp"
                bm.Save(full_name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            Case ".gif"
                bm.Save(full_name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
            Case ".jpg", "jpeg"
                bm.Save(full_name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Case ".png"
                bm.Save(full_name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            Case ".tiff"
                bm.Save(full_name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show( _
                    "Unknown file type " & ext & _
                    " in file " & filename, _
                    "Unknown File Type", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Select
    Next pic

    Beep()
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't get what you mean buy your comment can you explain more please

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that LastIndexOf isn't finding . in your filename. This then passes -1 to to SubString which throws the error you're seeing.

Instead of writing the file parsing yourself use the methods of System.Io.Path such as

```
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)
```

---

```
Private Sub btnSaveImages_Click(ByVal sender As  _
    System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
    btnSaveImages.Click

    For Each pic As PictureBox In flpPictures.Controls
        Dim bm As Bitmap = pic.Image
        Dim path As String = pic.Tag
        Dim filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
        Dim ext = IO.Path.GetExtension(path)
        Dim full_name = IO.Path.Combine(txtDirectory.txt, filename)
```

....

Comment: I've added an example.